# Saving JWT in cookie or local storage (node / angular 2 website)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, jwt

I know that jwt can be saved in local storage or cookies. But i couldn't find a good material online for instructions. How can i instruct server to recognize the user for future sessions.

```
    //authenticating users by username
router.route('/authentication').post(function(req, res) {
    User.findOne({username : req.body.username}, function(err, user){
        if (err) throw err;
        if (!user) {
            res.json({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. User not found.' });
        } else if (user) {

            // check if password matches
            if (user.password != req.body.password) {
                res.json({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. Wrong password.' });
            } else {

                // if user is found and password is right
                // create a token
                var token = jwt.sign({usern : user.username}, app.get('superSecret'), {
                //expiresInMinutes: 1440 // expires in 24 hours
                });
                res.cookie('auth',token);
                // return the information including token as JSON
                res.setHeader('token', token);
                res.json({
                success: true,
                message: 'Enjoy your token!',
                token: token
                });
            }   
        }
    });
})

app.use('/api', router);
```

Answer (score -1):

Token doesn't need to save on server, and this is one of the best things about token.
In server you need to check "hey, this token is signed by me? this token is expired?".
Like this code:

```
nJwt.verify(token, secretKey, function(err, jwt){
  if (err) {
    // something wrong
  }
}
```

Comment: yeah but how can server retrieve the token? After creating a token, where its saved in client?

Comment: After create token, send it to client. In client side you should save token in variable, and send token again to server with every single request.

Comment: i tried res.cookie('auth', token) and its not working. Whats your suggestion?

Comment: If you use cookie-parser can get token with this code:
req.cookies.rememberme

Comment: ok i will try that. Do you have any clue why res.cookie is not working in this case

Comment: It must work.
Can i see your entire code of this part?

Comment: This code has not problem. just check again app.use(express.cookieParser()) be in your code. now you should read your cookie with req.cookie.auth